# How do I mock a list of google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob objects?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, google-cloud-storage

I have a function that takes in a bunch of list of google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob objects to parse by date created that I want to unittest. How do I go about mocking it ? I thought about patching, but I realised that is more for calls within the function being tested. How do I mock the input of these blobs?
This is the function I want to test:

```
def bucket_parser(objects,start_time,end_time):
    file_count = 0
    latest_timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime('0000','%H%M')
    for file in objects:
        if file.time_created.time().replace(tzinfo=None) <= end_time and file.time_created.time().replace(tzinfo=None) >= start_time:
            file_count += 1
        if file.time_created.replace(tzinfo=None) > latest_timestamp.replace(tzinfo=None):
            latest_timestamp = file.time_created
    return file_count , latest_timestamp.time()
```

Where objects is of <class 'google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob'> and start and end time are of <class 'datetime.time'>. How can I go about unittesting this function with mocking ? I feel stuck because I am not sure how to go about it. Thank you.

Edit:
This the code which gets the blobs from the bucket, and passes them into the above function:

```
def bucket_scraper(bucket_name,bucket_prefix):
    '''
    Input: Bucket , Bucket Prefix
    Output: All objects/files in specified bucket prefix
    '''
    client = storage.Client()
    prefix_files = list(client.list_blobs(bucket_name,max_results = 700,page_token=None,prefix=bucket_prefix,delimiter='/'))
    return prefix_files
```

The returned prefix_files is what goes into the bucket_parser function.

Comment: @slideshowp2 could you please answer this question?

Comment: I didn't see `google.cloud.storage.blob.Blob`, how did you use it. Show the code

Comment: @slideshowp2 I have added the code that gets these blobs for the context, in my edit, hope that helps !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way in java on how to create a mock list of blobs, may be this will help (this is in test environment)

```
private List<Blob> getMockBlobList(int range){
        List<Blob> blobs = new ArrayList<>();
        for(int m = 0; m < range; m++){
            Blob blob = mock(Blob.class);
            when(mockReturnBlob.getName()).thenReturn("test-" + m +".pdf");
            //Add more returns to this blob
            blobs.add(blob);
        }

        return blobs;
    }
```

One way of using it is as

```
PageImpl<Blob> expectedBlobPage = new PageImpl<>(null, "c", List.of(getMockBlobList()));
```